# KendoUI Knockoutjs Dropdownlist

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, dropdown

I want to retrieve data from Kendo DropDownListe by using Kendo.

PS I want to do it without using Knockout-Kendo.js

PS There is a sample code that running on Jquery. See below

```
<input id="products" data-bind="DDList: { dataTextField: 'ProductName', dataValueField: 'ProductID', data: Product, value: selectedId }" />


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "ProductName",
        dataValueField: "ProductID",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

it is really hard to do things without this library(Knockout-Kendo.js).
My advice is to use it, or use only Kendo with data-bind.
Do this with the structure MVVM:
http://dojo.telerik.com/aTone